# Will Isa (peace be upon Him) come back? (Shia View)

Tags: prophet-isa, shiism

In this [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/5303/9) at the end, it says that the Mahdi will kill the Dajjal. I wonder if it is believed that Isa (peace be upon Him) will come back? If so, then what will be his (mission)? Will he kill the Dajjal? If not than will the Mahdi? which one of them will kill the Dajjal?

Comment: Since I'd misunderstood the exact meaning of your question, I decided to delete my answer.

Comment: @Ezati since my question has made some misunderstanding I have edited it, how is it now?

Comment: I think it's better to include sth about killing Dajjal in your topic as well

Comment: I think the original question was much better, and the answer, and comments, are quite a good explanation. I recommend undeleting.

Comment: To understand who will kill Dajjal you need to understand what actually is Dajjal. Please follow the link it's been explained in detail.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZqqm-M7HBA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsxtzN1_kmg

Answer (score 5):

Dajjal is a controversial topic among Muslim scholars. There are different interprets about it. Some say it is a system and not a person and some say he is a person. But there are some hadith saying there is not only one Dajjal but more than one and there will be many Dajjal starting after prophet. for example this this hadith says some of who saw prophet SAWW can see a Dajjal after death of prophet SAWW:

> "I heard the Messenger of Allah(s.a.w): 'There was never a Prophet
>   after Nuh but that he warned his people about the Dajjal, and indeed I
>   shall warn you of him.' Then the Messenger of Allah(s.a.w) described
>   him for us, and he said: "Perhaps some of you who see me, or hear my
>   words shall live to see him." They said: "O Messenger of Allah! How
>   will our hearts be on that day?" He said: "The same

Reference of hadith:  [Jami` at-Tirmidhi > Chapters On Al-Fitan](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/723940)

Shia scholars believe the Dajjal in this hadith who some of Scholars see him is Muaviyeh or Umayyad Kings. ([Ref](http://makarem.ir/websites/farsi/compilation/book.php?bcc=10404&itg=7&bi=137&s=ct))

About Jesus a.s. at revolution of Mahdi a.s. it is certain that Jesus a.s. will come and will pray behind Mahdi a.s. and will support and help him and many of Christians will convert to Islam when seeing Jesus a.s. praying behind Mahdi a.s.

> 9. Hudhayfah reported that the Prophet (‘s) said, “Al-Mahdí will turn his face to Jesus when he descends as if water were dropping from his
>      hair, and will say to him, ‘Go ahead and say the prayer.’ Jesus will
>      say, ‘The prayer has been set up only for you.’ So, Jesus will pray
>      behind a man who is among my sons.” (Siràt al-Mustaqím, 2, 257) ([ref](http://www.al-islam.org/jesus_shiite_narrations/))

Imam Mahdi a.s. will have an army with 313 top commanders and himself is leader. It is possible that Imam Mahdi a.s. send Jesus a.s. to a mission about fighting Dajjal. In this case it is correct if said any of them fight Dajjal.

Please note there are both authentic and non-authentic hadith about Mahdi a.s. and it is hard to determine details of what will happen.

But assuming it is authentic there is no problem is somewhere is said Dajjal will be killed by Mahdi a.s. and in some other place said will be killed by Jesus a.s. because Mahdi a.s. is leader and Jesus a.s. a supporter or commander of Mahdi a.s.

It is like that when a minister do a mission it can be attributed to president as well.

---

**References and more study:**

[Jesus through Shiite Narrations](http://www.al-islam.org/jesus_shiite_narrations/) (Chapter 11 Second Coming)

[Books about Imam Mahdi a.s.](http://www.maaref-foundation.com/english/library/pro_ahl/imam12_mahdi/index.htm)

[About Dajjal](http://makarem.ir/websites/farsi/compilation/book.php?bcc=10404&itg=7&bi=137&s=ct)

Comment: Also Allameh Kurani has stated that it is probable that Jesus will come to Christians and remain with them for some 5 or 6 years, at the time Imam Mahdi is with Muslims, then they will unite and Jesus will pray behind Mahdi, peace be upon them both. This is maybe because the Christians would not accept Islam very Immediately, they first need to renew their Christian beliefs that has been corrupted through the centuries, and this may be the main reason why Jesus will come back, also see [4:159] pointing to something like that, then in a few years Jesus will die and Imam will pray for him.